# Multiple notification with Alarm manager

Tags: java, android

I want to do a function that allows when I click on a button I choose a date and after I receive notification in these dates
This code just allows me to receive the last notification and not the others.

```
String dtStart = String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);
Calendar calendar;
Intent intent1;
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

intent1 = new Intent(getActivity(), AlarmReceiver.class);
intent1.putExtra("titrefr",titlefr);
intent1.putExtra("contentfr",contentfr);
intent1.putExtra("contentar",content);
intent1.putExtra("titrear",title);
intent1.putExtra("audio",stepAudio);
intent1.putExtra("image",image);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1000, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
//  am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening just because alarm id is overrides means when you set the alarm and you give 1000 id to each alarm.

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 1000, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

So when you set last time.Alarm manager set last time to id 1000 so last time alarm is working. I am simple adding a method that will help you to add multiple alarm

```
    private String setAlarm(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int min) {
                String value = "";
                calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
                if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddDrugFormActivity.this, "Select Valid Time", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    value = "INValid";
                } else {
                    value = "Valid";
                    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(AddDrugFormActivity.this, AlarmReciever.class);
  SharedPreferences preferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                    int id = preferences.getInt("id", 0);
                    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddDrugFormActivity.this, id, intentAlarm, 0);// set id 0 if single alarm require
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
                    id = id + 1;
                    editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt("id", id);
                    editor.commit();

                }
                return value;
            }
```

You just use this method to add multiple alarm. This is working code.